# How to pick the best model when doing an EFA with bifactor models?

Tags: r, chi-squared-test, factor-analysis, goodness-of-fit, confirmatory-factor

So, I'm running an EFA for a bifactor model. I've created models with different numbers of factors (between 2 and 13). After running an ANOVA, it's clear from the chi-square differences that the model must have at least 6 factors. It seems like a 10-factor model is a good fit (below RMSEA cutoff)...

But I really like the way the items are grouping together for a 7-factor solution (it also fits reasonably well based on cutoffs). The difference is that in the 7-factor solution, there are items that do not load onto the general or common factor.

My question is...is the best fitting model one where ALL items load onto the general factor? The 9-factor solution looks good, too...but there is one item that doesn't load onto the general factor.

Basically, it seems like there's something "off" with each model fit...either an item doesn't load onto the general factor or doesn't load onto a specific factor...

Which is most important here?

Thanks in advance :)

Comment: Can you share your results?

Answer (score 1):

There are many opinions on when and how to use [exploratory factor analysis (EFA)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Exploratory_factor_analysis#:%7E:text=In%20multivariate%20statistics%2C%20exploratory%20factor,underlying%20relationships%20between%20measured%20variables.), all of which require consideration of item content and the purpose of the analysis. So, regarding which of the 2-13 factor solutions you should pick, I would review both the literature and the item content. Put differently, psychometricians and statisticians disagree on quite a few things. However, the importance of incorporating things such as item content and theory into your decision process is not one of them.

Additionally, what type of EFA are you using? I ask because not all EFA techniques incorporate the bifactor restriction, which is essential if you assume such a structure likely underlies your data (e.g., see Mansolf & Reise, 2016).

Finally, I would not suggest selecting a model based on the fit of an EFA model (e.g., see Montoya & Edwards, 2021) unless your final model allows for all items to load onto all factors (which is seldom, if ever, what is done, unless the purpose is pure dimensionality reduction. In which case model fit would not be important anyways).

**References**

Mansolf, M., & Reise, S. P. (2016). Exploratory bifactor analysis: The Schmid-Leiman orthogonalization and Jennrich-Bentler analytic rotations. Multivariate Behavioral Research, 51(5), 698-717.

Montoya, A. K., & Edwards, M. C. (2021). The poor fit of model fit for selecting the number of factors in exploratory factor analysis for scale evaluation. Educational and psychological measurement, 81(3), 413-440.

Comment: Hi there-- thanks! I'm using the omega function from the psych package in R, with maximum likehlihood and oblimin rotation.

Also thank you so much-- this is already much clearer. I will check out those resourcs.